# Validation in Java of an XML file using more schemas, but against only one of those schemas

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I need to validate an XML file using more namespace, each declared in an external schema; something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:root xmlns:foo="http://foo.com" xmlns:bar="http://bar.com">
    <foo:inside bar:bar="foobar"/>
</foo:root>
```

However, I don't have to validate the file against all schemas, as I have to check compliance only for one of them.

I tried everyting: SAX, DOM, LSParser, but the file is always validated against all schemas. Even using the single schema validator doesn't help, which is quite puzzling to me (incidentally, the validation fails, as the XML doesn't specify the schemas location). I also tried to "fake" the schemas I'm not interested in, so that validation for those schemas can pass, but I didn't manage to make a good one.

I'm looking for a small example that shows me how to validate the XML against only one of the used schemas, no matter how invalid the rest of the XML is in regard to the other ones. I have to say I'm starting to think it's not possible, but considering how strange it sounds I still might be missing something.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice is really to fake all "not interesting" schemas.

Or you can add your own ErrorListener and carefully analyze the errors to determine the schema they relate to. But this might not be full proof since there can be "other schema"-related errors that stop the validation.

Comment: thanks. I looked again at that solution. I basically make a schema with one element, which has a sequence with an xs:any in it. I'm seeing that maybe it doesn't work as bad as I thought, so I'll have a look at it. I wonder if there can be limitations though, as I'm not completely sure of how validation works within an xs:any element.
I also looked at the error listener thing, but for what I know the information about the error comes in form of the location in the file; no information about namespaces or schemas

Answer (score 0):

It would help to get the terminology straight. A "schema document" is a single XSD file rooted at an xs:schema element. A "schema" is any consistent collection of schema components, typically the result of processing a number of schema documents for different target namespaces, linked using xs:include and xs:import. We can regard such a schema as being partitioned by target namespace, so the "schema for a namespace" is the result of processing a number of schema documents, typically linked using xs:include, that share the same target namespace.

It seems that you are validating against schema S, and you want to validate against schema T which is a subset of the schema components in S.

So when you say that "each namespace [is] declared in an external schema" I don't think you are using "schema" in the correct sense. I suspect you mean schema document. But then I wonder what you mean by "declared"? How are you telling the schema validator where to find the schema for each namespace? Is it my means of an xsi:schemaLocation attribute, or by some other mechanism? Because whatever mechanism you are using, this is what you need to change in order to validate against a different schema.

Comment: yes, correct, sorry. I was more talking about schema documents. Each schema document has its own target namespace. It is a terminology that unfortunately is used quite often.
Concerning the second part, I'm not sure I understand. As I wrote, the XML doesn't specify the location of the schema documents, and that is something I can't change (I am not the author). Also, I am interested only in the location of one schema, the one I have to validate my XML against. I give its location either by using a resource resolver or by using a validator for that specific schema

Comment: Well, the schema validator must have discovered the location of the "unwanted" schema documents from somewhere, and it's not clear to me from your answer where that somewhere is. Wherever it is, that's what needs to change.

Comment: mmmh... maybe I wasn't clear. The validator doesn't discover any location of the documents, which is why the validation fails. But it does try, as I can see in my resolver. And that is exactly the problem: I need it to skip the validation of the parts I'm not interested in. No validation, no searching for documents, nothing besides correct XML. Only for the part I'm interested in, specifically the part that is coming from a specific namespace (and from a specific document)

Comment: I think you are going to have to modify either your source document or your schema to achieve this partial validation. Modifying the source document is probably easier. Consider putting it through a SAX filter before it reaches the validator.

Comment: Yes, that is something I have considered, but I'm not sure I can do that without consequences. At the moment I'm thinking of replacing the "uninteresting" elements with dummies defined by me as elements taking any content, and removing the uninteresting attributes. Not sure this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Extend [`XmlFilterImpl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLFilterImpl.html) (a SAX filter) to remove the tags from other namespaces (and everything inside those tags) before the schema validator sees them. The namespace for each tag is passed to `startElement()`, so it's trivial to just filter out everything until the corresponding `endElement()` is called.

```
class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {
    // filter out content from other namespaces
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.xml.sax.XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        NamespaceFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();
        filter.setParent(reader);
        javax.xml.validation.Schema schema = /* get a schema */;
        filter.setContentHandler(schema.newValdiatorHandler()); 
        filter.parse(/* xml file */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some time has passed, and at the end we gave up on this one. But thanks for the answer. I actually came up with a workaround that is not much different: I was thinking of replacing those tags, instead of removing them, with some dummy tags that would allow validation to pass. But the solution was so complex that at the end, as I said, we gave up